# Postgres unique constraint on groups of rows

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, unique-constraint

I'm using postgresql 10.12

I have labeled entities. Some are standard, some are not. Standard entities are shared among all users, whereas not standard entities are user owned. So let's say I have a table `Entity` with a text column `Label`, and a column `user_id` which is null for standard entities.

```
CREATE TABLE Entity
(
  id uuid NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id integer,
  label text NOT NULL,
)
```

Here is my constraint : two not standard entities belonging to different users can have the same label. Standard entities labels are unique, and entities of a given users have unique labels. The hard part is: a label must be unique within a group of standard entities + a given user's entities.

I'm using sqlAlchemy, here is the constraints I've made so far:

```
__table_args__ = (
    UniqueConstraint("label", "user_id", name="_entity_label_user_uc"),
    db.Index(
        "_entity_standard_label_uc",
        label,
        user_id.is_(None),
        unique=True,
        postgresql_where=(user_id.is_(None)),
    ),
)
```

My problem with this constraint is that I do not guarantee that a user entity won't have a standard entity label.

Example:

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id |   label    |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 | null    | std_ent    |
|  2 | 42      | user_ent_1 |
|  3 | 42      | user_ent_2 |
|  4 | 43      | user_ent_1 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

This is a valid table. I want to make sure that it is not possible anymore to create an entity with label `std_ent`, that user 42 cannot create another entity with label `user_ent_1` or `user_ent_2` and that user 43 cannot create another entity with label `user_ent_1`.

With my current constraints, it is still possible for users 42 and 43 to create an entity with label `std_ent`, which is what I want to fix.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your unique constraint(s) are doing their job of preventing users from entering duplicate labels for their own "user entities" then you can prevent them from entering the label of a "standard entity" by adding a trigger.

You create a function …

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.std_label_check()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    begin
        if exists(
                select * from entity 
                where label = new.label and user_id is null) then
            raise exception '"%" is already a standard entity', new.label;
        end if;
        return new;
    end;
$function$
;
```

… and then attach it as a trigger to the table

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER entity_std_label_check
BEFORE INSERT 
ON public.entity FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE std_label_check()
```

Comment: If I have to code a function instead of a constraint, I'd rather have it checked directly at the API view level instead, keeping all my function in python. Thank you for your solution anyway! It does what I need.